# What do these three towns have in common?

Tags: language

What do these three towns have in common?

"Dublin", "Blackpool", "Chernobyl".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three of them

> have the first part of their name meaning "black". ("Dublin" literally means "black pool"; "Chernobyl" literally means "black grass".)

Comment: Heh! Too simple. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

If you allow for some creative linguistics, they all have

> **very** similar names.

Dublin

> comes from the Gaelic "dubh linn", meaning “black pool”

and Chernobyl

> while meaning "common wormwood", or "mugwort", comes from two parts:
>  - "cherno" (from chornyi, "black") and
>  - "byl" (from bylia, "grass"), which sounds a bit like "pool".